# How to avoid masses of data loads in CQRS/DDD Commands/Events?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, ddd-repositories, domain-model

We have an DDD AppDomain containing Seminars, Participants and their Meals. We have up to 1000 Participants per Seminar with up to 50 Meals per Participant. We decided that Seminars, Participants an Meals are aggregates to keep these aggregates small.
The user can reschedule a whole seminar with all participants or reschedule a single participant. So we have the commands "RescheduleSeminarCommand" and "RescheduleParticipantCommand".

The Problem arises when you reschedule a Seminar: The "RescheduleSeminarCommand" leads to a "SeminarRescheduledEvent" which leads to a "RescheduleParticipantCommand" per Participant. That would mean loading each single Participant from the repository - so 1000 database requests. Each "RescheduleParticipantCommand" leads to a "ParticipantRescheduledEvent" which fires "RescheduleMealsCommand" which loads the Meals for each single Participant - so another 1000 database requests.

How can we reduce the number of database requests?

1) We thought about extending the "RescheduleParticipantCommand" and the "RescheduleMealsCommand" with the SeminarId so we can not only load one Participant/Meal but all Participants/Meals for a whole Seminar.

2) Another way would be to create additional Events/Commands like for "RescheduleParticipantsForSeminarCommand", "ParticipantsForSeminarRescheduleEvent" and "RescheduleMealsForSeminarCommand" etc.

What do you think is better? 1), 2) or something different we didn't think of?

---

OK, I'll give some details which i missed in my first description:

If have the following classes

```
class Seminar
{
    UUID SeminarId,
    DateTime Begin,
    DateTime End
}

// Arrival/Departure of a participant may differ
// from Begin/End of the seminar
class Participant
{
    UUID ParticipantId
    UUID SeminarId,
    DateTime Arrival,
    DateTime Departure
}

// We have one Meal-Object for breakfast, one for lunch and 
// one for dinner (and additional for other meals) per day 
// of the stay of the participant
class Meal
{
    UUID MealId,
    UUID ParticipantId,
    DateTime Date,
    MealType MealType
}
```

The users can

- change Arrival/Depature of a single participant with the "RescheduleParticipantCommand" which would also change their Meals to the new dates.
- change Begin/End of a seminar with the "RescheduleSeminarCommand" which would change the Arrival/Depature of all participants to the new Begin/End and change their meals accordingly.

Comment: At first sight it seems a wrong aggregate design in your Schedule bounded context but I would need extended info about what changes in every command execution and why to confirm it and maybe give you a useful response . Could you extend the question with a workflow example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added some details in my description. Please see above.

Comment: Thanks but you forgot to post the most important info: rules. Could every single participant reject the Arrival/Departure change? What happend then? You reschedule half of participants or just cancel the whole seminar reschedule? And the same question with meals.

Comment: While I wait for a response I want to point you about one thing: Commands are things that could be rejected by your domain rules. If you raise a command due to a event (something that already is done and can not be rejected because it passes all domain rules) keep in mind that; even if the new command does nothing because is rejected; your system has to be in a consistent state. Basic rule: If you raise a event is because the system is in a consistent state even if that event implies more commands in the system that could be rejected or does not change nothing in the system.

Comment: Ok. Some rules:

- When I have a seminar from 06/01/2019 to 06/05/2019 and I reschedule it to 06/02/2019 to 06/06/2019 then all participants should get Arival at 06/02/2019 and Departure at 06/06/2019 and their meals per day should be changed accordingly 

- When I have a participant from 06/03/2019 to 06/06/2019 and i reschedule to 06/04/2019 to 06/06/2019 then the meals should be changed accourdingly

Comment: So, once Seminar aggregate acepts the new dates you change Participants dates without the needed to check more rules? Then here are you are your solution without reading 1000 participants: Update Seminar
(
  Begin
, End)
Values
(
  '06/02/2019'
  ,06/06/2019
)
where SeminarID = @SeminarID;

Update Participant
(
  Arrival
, Departure
)
Values
(
  '06/02/2019'
  ,06/06/2019
)
where SeminarId = @SeminarID

Comment: You do not want finegrained commands for this kind of behaviour. Read my comment about commands to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a concept of ***SeminarSchedule***. First let's ask couple of questions that will affect the model

- If you have a Seminar, is it divided to some sort of Lecture, Presentation etc. or is it a seminar of the same thing just for different people at different times?
- Can you sign a person to the seminar first and then decide what time this person will attend?

I'll give an example in pseudo code.

*NOTE: I'll skip the meals as the question is about the scheduling but they do fit in this model. I'll discuss logic related to them too, just skip them in code*

First let's say what our requirements are.

- It's a seminar for one thing (lecture, train session whatever) divided into time slots. The same lecture will be given to different people starting at different times.
- Participants can sign without being scheduled to a time slot.
- When a participant signs, we need to make a meal for him/her based on preferences (for example he/she may be a vegetarian or vegan).
- Scheduling will be done at a specific time from users of the system. They will take participants info when doing the schedule. For example we may want to have people with the same age in one time slot or by some other criteria.

Here's the code:

```
class Seminar {
    UUID ID;
    // other info for seminar like description, name etc.
}

class Participant {
    UUID ID;
    UUID SeminarID;
    // other data for participant, name, age, meal preferences etc.
}

class TimeSlot {

    Time StartTime;
    TimeInterval Duration;
    ReadonlyCollection<UUID> ParticipantIDs;

    void AddParticipant(UUID participantID) { }
}

class SeminarSchedule {

    UUID SeminarID;

    Date Date;
    Time StartTime;
    TimeInterval Duration;

    ReadOnlyCollection<TimeSlot> TimeSlots;

    void ChangeDate(Date newDate) { }
    void ChangeStartTime(Time startTime) { }
    void ChangeDuration(TimeInterval duration) { }
    void ScheduleParticipant(Participant p, Time timeSlotStartTime) { }
    void RemoveParticipantFromSchedule(Participant p) { }
    void RescheduleParticipant(Participant p, Time newTimeSlotStartTime) { }
}
```

Here we have 3 aggregates: `Seminar`, `Participant` and `SeminarSchedule`.

If you need to change any information related to the `Seminar` or `Participant` you only target these aggregates.

On the other hand if you need to do anything related to the schedule, the `SeminarSchedule` aggregate (being a transactional boundary around scheduling) will handle these command ensuring consistency. You can also enforce concurrency control over the schedule. You may not want multiple people changing the schedule at the same time. For example one changing the `StartTime` while another changing the `Duration` or having two users add the same participant to the schedule. You can use [Optimistic Offline lock](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html) on the `SeminarSchedule` aggregate

For instance changing the `Duration` of `StartTime` of a `SeminarSchedule` will affect all `TimeSlots`.

If you remove a `Participant` from the `Seminar` then you will have to remove it from the schedule too. This can be implemented with eventual consistency and handling `ParticipantRemoved` event or you can use a [Saga](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html).

Another thing we need to take into account when modelling aggregates is also how the logic of signing to a seminar works.

Let's say that a participant should sign to the Seminar first before scheduling them.  Maybe the scheduling will be performed later by defining groups of people by some criteria. The above model will work fine. It will allow for users to sign a `Participant` to the `Seminar`. Later when the schedule is assigned, other users will be able to make the schedule by looking at what kind of participants have signed.

Let's take the opposite case and say that unscheduled participants cannot be present to the seminar.

In this case we can add the `Participant` entity to the `SeminarSchedule` aggregate but this will cause you to load this whole aggregate even when you need to change some information for a single participant. This isn't very practical.

So order to keep the nice separation that we have, we may use a ***Saga*** or a ***ProcessManager*** to ensure consistency. We may also add the concept of a `ReservedPlace` in the `SeminarSchedule` aggregate. This way you can reserve a place, then add a participant to the schedule and then remove the `ReservedPlace` by assigning the participant to the time slot. As this is a complex process that spans multiple aggregates a `Saga` is definitely in place.

Another way to do this is to define a concept of a `SeminarSignRequest` that a person can make. Later this request may be approved if meals and/or a place is available. We may have reached the maximum number of people or not have enough meals etc. This probably also be a process so you may need a `Saga` here too.

For more information, check [this article](https://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Y-XPlXOWoA).

Answer (score 0):

Commands are things that could be rejected by your domain rules. If you raise a command due to a event (something that already is done and can not be rejected because it passes all domain rules) keep in mind that; even if the new command does nothing because is rejected; your system has to be in a consistent state. Basic rule: If you raise a event is because the system is in a consistent state even if that event implies more commands in the system that could be rejected or does not change nothing in the system.

So, according to your comments once Seminar aggregate acepts the new dates according its rules; you change Participants dates without the needed to check more rules.

Then the solution is just change everything in persistence and not spam finegrained commands for every change you want.

Relational Database example:

```
Update Seminar ( Begin , End) Values ( '06/02/2019' ,06/06/2019 ) where SeminarID = @SeminarID;

Update Participant ( Arrival , Departure ) Values ( '06/02/2019' ,06/06/2019 ) where SeminarId = @SeminarID
```

PS: Why not having just Seminar Begin/End in persistence and bring this data in the hidratation of Paricipants (Arrival/Departure) aggregate? This way you always have a consistent state in your system without worry about changing several things.